# how to apply the condition in django model

Tags: django, orm

I have some model class like.

```
class user(models.Model):

Student = 's'
Hostel = 'h'
Pg = 'p'
type_of_user = (
    (Student, 'Student'),
    (Hostel, 'Hostel'),
    (Pg, 'PG')
)
u_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=type_of_user, default=Student)
```

and i have another class

```
class student(models.Model)
s_id = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but i apply the condition on s_id (show only that user where u_type=student)

Comment: You could add a custom validation by overriding the model's `clean()` method. In that method you would raise a `ValidationError` if the `user` assigned doesn't have the correct type. So when creating a new `student` via a form, when checking if the form is valid, you'd get `False` if you try to assign a wrong user. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for how `clean()` works.

Answer (score 0):

what @dirkgroten just said is actually one of the possible solution to add condition but there is possible to add model field level validation. Django allow to add custome validation function in model field level [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#writing-validators) . And also if you are using serializer add custom validation there also another possible solution.

Comment: KaushalGajjar though i think if @dirkgroten post an answer you should accept this. If he isnot posting you can accept my answer as an answer of your question. So that this question will treat as solved issue in SO. Thank you for your appreciation :)